# FolderDialog em ConsoleApplication C#

Tags: c#, .net

Estou com uma dúvida relacionada a Console Application, como eu faço para abrir uma janela semelhante a esta onde é possível selecionar um PASTA? 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seria um recurso igual ao que existe em WindowsForms onde é [FolderBrowserDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx/).

Utilizo o .NET Framework 4.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça deste modo,

Basta instanciar e chamar.

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (var path in Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(path); // full path
                Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path)); // file name
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270387/browse-for-folder-in-console-application

**TEM QUE ADICIONAR A REF. para System.Windows.Forms**

como o nosso amigo @Iago Correia Guimarães lembrou bem.

Comment: e referenciar o System.Windows.Forms

Comment: Isso isso isso.

Comment: Era o que eu procurava, obrigado :D